# Create a snapshot for a transaction?

Tags: sql-server

PostgreSQL has a feature to [create a snapshot for a transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-set-transaction.html) using:

```
SET TRANSACTION SNAPSHOT snapshot_id
```

Does SQL Server have a similar feature?

I have an application program that uses a SQL Server backend.  It invokes two read-only queries Q1 and Q2 using separate connections.  This means they do not execute in the same transaction.  I need to ensure both connections see the database in the same precise state, as would be afforded via the `SET TRANSACTION SNAPSHOT` statement in PostgreSQL.

How can I ensure both Q1 and Q2 see the database in a consistent state, identical to both connections?

Comment: You can read uncommited data, but that can be from any transaction

Comment: AFAIK, SQL Server does not support the ability to 'share' transactions like this PostgreSQL feature. Why are the queries using separate connections? Could you wrap the Q1 and Q2 code into a stored procedure to ensure the results are consistent? Can you write out the results from Q1 into a global temp table and access that in Q2 instead to ensure you read the same data? Lastly, and a bit heavy-handed, can you create a database snapshot at the beginning of Q1 and read data from that for Q1 and Q2?

Answer (score 4):

So there *is* a way to do this using a couple of features that have probably never been used together in the real world: snapshot isolation and bound sessions.

[Bound Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-bindsession-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in particular is an extremely old, obscure and deprecated feature (although like many deprecated features it may never actually be removed).

Anyway the procedure `sp_bindsession` allows a session to participate in a transaction started by a different session.  And if both sessions are in SNAPSHOT isolation, then they will share a point-in-time consistent view of the database.

So setup:

```
create database testdb
alter database testdb set allow_snapshot_isolation on
go
use testdb
drop table if exists t
create table t(id int)
```

Then from one session:

```
--session 1
use testdb 
if @@trancount > 0 rollback

set transaction isolation level snapshot
begin transaction

declare @token varchar(255)
exec sp_getbindtoken @token out 
select @token 


insert into t(id) values (1)
```

and from another session, after copying and pasting the bind token:

```
--session 2
use testdb
go

set transaction isolation level snapshot
declare @token varchar(255) = '7-`L>5B0-1[OgFb4FVTWU]5---/=AM--'

select @@trancount --returns 0

exec sp_bindsession @token 

select @@trancount --returns 1

go

select * from t --returns a row

rollback --rolls back the transaction started in the other session

go

select * from t --no rows
```

But any real-world scenario, you should probably either use [Multiple Active Result Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/multiple-active-result-sets-mars) and run the queries in the same session, or create a [Database Snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-snapshots-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)